# What is the treewidth of the 3D-grid (mesh or lattice) with sidelength n?

Tags: graph-theory, treewidth

Here, by 3D-grid of sidelength $n$ I mean the graph $G=(V,E)$ with $V= \{1,\ldots,n\}^3$ and $E=\{( (a,b,c) ,(x,y,z) ) \mid |a-x|+|b-y|+|c-z|=1 \}$.

I known how to get the treewidth of $n*n$ grid is exactly $n$ from bramble:

1. Firstly, we can construct a tree decomposition of $width=n$, which means $tw(n*n)\leq n$
2. Secondly, we can construct a bramble of order n, which means $tw(n*n)\geq n-1$

> [a graph has a bramble of order $k$ if and only if it has treewidth at least $k − 1$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895683710270?via%3Dihub)

However, for a $n*n*n$ grid. We can simply get a path decomposition with pathwidth=$\Theta(n^2)$. But I don't know how to construct a bramble of order $n^2$ to confirm its lower bound.

**My question:** What is the treewidth of the 3D-grid (mesh or lattice) with sidelength n?

Comment: It is $\Omega(n^2)$ from a well-linked set argument but if you want a tight bound in terms of constants I do not know the right/clean answer.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri $\Omega(n^2)$ is enough, I believe well-linked argument is right. However,  I can't exactly write the proof about the size of  $n^2$-linked set, how to describe there are enough paths?

Comment: @ChandraChekuri Do you know bramble argument for $n*n*n$ grid?

Comment: Related question (notice that treewidth <= pathwidth): https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4081/what-is-the-pathwidth-of-the-3d-grid-mesh-or-lattice-with-sidelength-k

Comment: @HermannGruber. I have gone through this answer and it can only provide an upper bound of treewidth if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Jxb yes, that answer provides only an upper bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $\Theta(n^2)$. The argument to prove the lower bound is that we can send an all-pairs concurrent flow of value $1$ and congestion $O(n^4)$, i.e., we can simultaneously send one unit of flow between every pair of vertices so that at most $O(n^4)$ units of flow go through any single vertex. This implies treewidth at least $\Omega(n^2)$, because on treewidth-$k$ graphs with $|V|$ vertices any such flow must have congestion at least $\Omega(|V|^2/k)$.

The construction to send the flow is as follows: Consider a pair of vertices represented by coordinates $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$. We send one flow path of value one that goes with straight lines $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$->$(x_2,y_1,z_1)$->$(x_2,y_2,z_1)$->$(x_2,y_2,z_2)$.

Now, given a vertex $(x,y,z)$, for how many pairs $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ does their flow path go through $(x,y,z)$? We observe that for a flow path between $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ to go through $(x,y,z)$, at least two coordinates of $(x,y,z)$ must be equal to a corresponding coordinate in either $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ or $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$. Therefore, when given $(x,y,z)$, we have four degrees of freedom when selecting the pair $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, so the number of such pairs is $O(n^4)$.

Comment: One can use similar routing to show that the $n^2$ vertices of the side of the grid is $c$-well-linked set for some fixed constant $c < 1$. A set $X$ is a $c$-well-linked set if for any partition of $X$ into $A$ and $B$ there are $\min(|A|,|B|)$ disjoint paths between $A$ and $B$ with congestion at most $c$. It is known that treewidth and size of well-linked sets are within a small constant of each other.

Comment: This is a new concept for me,  could you please offer some tutorials? I was even more confused after a Google search.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a clean survey to point to. You can read a bit about these connections in a paper of mine with Julia Chuzhoy. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.6577.pdf (see Section 2 which describes well-linked sets and connection to treewidth).  I also like Bruce Reed's survey on treewidth and tangles. https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/surveys-in-combinatorics-1997/tree-width-and-tangles-a-new-connectivity-measure-and-some-applications/50B61BC367CC21EA85F02038F3CC632D

Comment: @ChandraChekuri. Yeah, I can learn the connection between treewidth and well-linked sets from your paper. But I don't understand the connection of "congestion" and treewidth from Laakeri's answer.